# unable to read tcp/ip headers

Tags: tcp, network-programming, ip

i am getting this error:‘struct iphdr’ has no member named ‘ip_ttl’
same for other members too but not for protocol feild
what is the solution to it?and y does it happen?
PS:I saw this on various forums but couldn't get why is it able to access ipHeader->protocol and not others

Comment: Could you post some code? Also, isn't the field just 'ttl' and not 'ip_ttl'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Linux, try taking a look at `/usr/include/linux/ip.h`. That header file defines the structure:

```
struct iphdr {
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
    __u8    ihl:4,
        version:4;
#elif defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
    __u8    version:4,
        ihl:4;
#else
#error  "Please fix <asm/byteorder.h>"
#endif
    __u8    tos;
    __be16  tot_len;
    __be16  id;
    __be16  frag_off;
    __u8    ttl;
    __u8    protocol;
    __sum16 check;
    __be32  saddr;
    __be32  daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
};
```

As you can see, the name of the field is `ttl`, not `ip_ttl`.

Comment: `ip_ttl` is from the BSD-compatible IP header declaration found in `/usr/include/netinet/ip.h`.